# Acumatica Contact base webservice with android development

Tags: android, acumatica

Step1:
I want to develop my own android application for connecting with acumatica contact base webservice. I try to research for this solution but I cannot get it yet. If someone know how to do it, please help me to solve this problem.

Step2: After I research for this solution. I get some trick key but I cannot convert from C# code to android code as below
[Acumatica Rest Api Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvKup.png)

[My Android Code connect to Acumatica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMZ2.png)

It's always to show Message:: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 6677): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused). I think because of HttpURLConnection Authenticate header is not post to server. Could you help me ?

Comment: There are training courses and help documentation provided by Acumatica for working with contact based web services. Have you looked into a site instance help file and the training courses? (they are unrelated to Andriod development but provide the standard calls to make to web services for Acumatica)

Comment: also, keep in mind that Acumatica already has an app which you can modify per site instance to display and manage data without having to write anything specific in a custom andriod app.

Comment: I know acumatica have android app and we can customize to display module. But It cannot work offline mode. So I try to develop my own app.

Comment: understood. The help articles and even more so the training as it includes working examples should help answer your question.